# Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.2 is missing .NET Core SDK location

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, sdk, visual-studio-mac

After the latest update of VS4Mac to v.8.10.2 (build 17), the .NET Core SDK location is missing after each relaunch of Visual Studio for Mac.

In preferences it has correct path to the symbolic link, but it fails to parse values (symbolic link exists, checked in Finder).
[image: Missing SDK]

It finds sdk when I write the direct location:
[image: Found SDK]

The problem is that after relaunch of Visual Studio for Mac, the Location is set back to the default value `/usr/local/bin/dotnet`

Does anyone knows workaround for this issue or maybe there's somebody from VS4Mac team who can promote this issue to be fixed in the nearest build of VS4Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10. It should be fixed in a service release, which is pending.

The problem is that Visual Studio for Mac is not resolving the symlink you have at `/usr/local/bin/dotnet`. This symlink points to the real install dotnet cli at `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`.

The current workaround is to remove that `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` symlink.

This was introduced in Visual Studio for Mac 8.10 since it now supports resolving dotnet cli from the PATH. Unfortunately it finds the dotnet symlink (if you have it) and then you cannot fix the setting permanently in preferences, since the path being set is the default `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet` ando it does not save the value, which is then lost on restarting.